# creating multiple objects with browserify

Tags: javascript, oop, browserify

I am trying to use the design pattern as below:

human.js

```
function Human(name){
    this.name = name
    this.sayName = function(){
         console.log(this.name);
    }
}

var a = new Human("bob");
var b = new Human("ted");
```

However I haven't used browserify much and I don't know how to do this in browserify.

What I notice is when I require human.js and then try to create a new object, it appears to be replacing the old object.

How do I use browserify for this design pattern?

Rest of my code is something along the lines of:

```
module.exports = {
    MyHuman:Human
}
```

and in file 1:

```
var human = require('human.js')
var ted = new Human('ted')
ted.sayName();
```

and in file 2:

```
var human = require('human.js')
var bob = new Human('bob')
bob.sayName();
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to export the Human class from human.js or instances of the Human class?

Comment: Im trying to create a class so that i can create multiple instances elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CommonJS (Browserify), what you export will be what you get when you call require (however, be careful with assuming what you export is a singleton, it's not always the case from my experience). So in this case, you want to export the Human class directly. Then in each file that you need to instantiate human, require the class and instantiate from there.

human.js

```
function Human(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sayName = function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  };
}

module.exports = Human;
```

file 1

```
var Human = require('./human.js');
var ted = new Human('Ted');
ted.sayName();
```

file 2

```
var Human = require('./human.js');
var bob = new Human('Bob');
bob.sayName();
```